# Objective-c create variables in a loop

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to create variables inside of a loop. Basically something like this, except that the variables variable1, variable2 and variable3 would exist.

```
int x;

for (x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
   int variable[x]; 
   variable[x] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there isn't.

But you can do something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    [dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
}
```

This will save your `x`s in an `NSMutableDictionary`, which is comparable to an associative array in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about variable names incorrectly. What you are looking for is a data structure such as an array which is index based or a [dictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ([hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)) to hold these values.

Answer (score 0):

YOu could use an array and set each value however you like. in your example you have a fixed for loop, so you can define an array of 4, and iterate.

Code:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];

for (int x=0; x<4; x++)
{
    [myArray addObject:x]; 
}
//you now have an array of 4 int like this: [1,2,3,4]
```