# Add integer to end of variable name Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I am new to Objective-C but at a decent level with java, let's say for example I have a loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
  NSString *(newstring+'i');
}
```

I want to end up with newstring0, newstring1, newstring2 for example.

How is this possible in Objective c?

Thanks,
Oli

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-c create variables in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846728/objective-c-create-variables-in-a-loop)

Comment: Use the method of NSString named [stringWithFormat:@"newstring%d",i], %d stands for integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"newString%d",i];
        NSLog(@"my string :: %@", newString);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont think I clearly stated what I meant. I mean I want the name of the string variable to contain the integer. For example if I made a new nsobject I would want to call it object1, object 2 etc, not what is contained in the variable.

Comment: hi, if you want to differentiate an object from other example :objectN, then you can use tag, so you can use objectN.tag = 1, so when you want to call that object you use tag again